# Trigger form submit programmatically after preventDefault() - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

The code is as follows

```
 <form
    name="orderForm"
    method="post"
    action="{{action}}"
    ng-submit="onSubmit($event)"
 >
   ...
</form>
```

To prevent the form submit i have used

```
scope.onSubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(valid condition) {
      // submit form programmatically
      // scope.orderForm.ngSubmit.emit(); doesn't seem to work
    }    
};
```

Now i need to submit the form programmatically when a specific condition is satisfied. 
i have used **scope.orderForm.ngSubmit.emit()** but doesnt seem to work.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Try the other way around

```
scope.onSubmit = function (e) {
    // If valid condition fails
    if (!validCondition) {
        // prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else { 
        // Do your API call here
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$event.target.submit()`:

```
scope.onSubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(valid condition) {
      // submit form programmatically
      // scope.orderForm.ngSubmit.emit(); doesn't seem to work

      //Trigger submit
      e.target.submit()
    }    
};
```

**Note**

Since the role of forms in client-side AngularJS applications is different than in classical roundtrip apps, it is **desirable for the browser not to translate the form submission into a full page reload** that sends the data to the server. Instead use the [$http Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to make HTTP POST requests to the server.

For more information, see

- [MDN Web API Reference - HTMLFormElement.submit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit)
- [AngularJS `<form>` Directive API Reference - Submitting a form and preventing the default action](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action)
- [Angular JS Developer Guide - Form Validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation)